# url attribute of <h:graphicImage/> not accepting 2nd request parameter

Tags: jsf

I use a Servlet to stream an image from the database and I use the  tag for display as follows:

```
<h:graphicImage url=”/servletUrl?para1=name1&para2=name2”/>
```

The problem starts if I include the 2nd parameter (&para2=name2) and I get the following error message:

*The reference to entity "para2" must end with the ';' delimiter*

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ampersand `&` is actually an special character in XML. The ampersand is to be used to indicate the start of a XML entity like `&gt;`, `&lt;` and so on. Hence the exception message that it is expecting a `;` which indicates the end of a XML entity.

To represent a standalone ampersand, you need to represent it as `&amp;`.

```
<h:graphicImage url="/servletUrl?para1=name1&amp;para2=name2" />
```

(note that I fixed the invalid curly quotes as well)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer accepted. See also http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: I can't find any links to mark this answer as accepted which I really like to do. This may be due to I am new and having only 1 reputation point. Thanks again.